# How to filter avro records through filtering with a list of another file in pig?

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I have a file "fileA" that is an avro with the following records:

```
{itemid:"Carrot"}
{itemid:"Lettuce"}
...
```

I have another file "fileB" that is an avro with multiple records following the same schema:

```
{item: "Carrot", cost: $2, ...other fields..}
{item: "Lettuce", cost: $2, ...other fields..}
{item: "Rice", cost: $2, ...other fields..}
...
```

How can I use pig to filter the data such that I can store all the relevant records in file "B" in a new output file?

I tried performing the following:

```
A = load 'fileA' using AvroStorage();
B = load 'fileB' using AvroStorage();

C = JOIN A by itemid , B by item;

STORE C into 'outputpath' using AvroStorage();
```

I am getting an error of "Pig Schema contains a name that is not allowed in Avro.
I want to avoid having to specify the complete schema of "B" inside of the AvroStorage() or any fields in A, as I only want to use A to filter down the records of B for storage and not add or change any of the schema output of B. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code... Can you show the exact error you are receiving ?

Comment: According to the source code of avro, an error like this is shown if a field does not match this regex : "[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*", maybe you have a field in one of you file that doesn't match it.

Comment: Have your tried 
STORE C into 'outputpath' using AvroStorage('record','-doublecolon');

Link: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#AvroStorage

"-doublecolons or -d Specify how to handle Pig schemas that contain double-colons [...]